# Alguem sabe me explicar o processo de gerar uma apk no React Native

Tags: react-native

Não consigo de jeito nenhum gerar uma apk, sigo os passos da documentação mas logo de cara nao consigo gerar a keytool. Alguem sabe pode me explicar como se gera?

Comment: Podes dar um printscreen ao erro que tens? (Não tenho reputação para comentar apenas)

Comment: se tiver o erro ajuda bastante.

Comment: Opa, criei meu apk seguindo o tutorial da resposta da sua pergunta. Porém o apk gerado não funciona quando upo o mesmo pro google play. Você conseguiu gerar, upar e executar de boa?

Answer (score 12):

Para gerar uma apk ~signed~ você precisa primeiro gerar a .keystore.

Esse passo é bem simples. Apenas vá até onde você colocou sua jdk (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_x\bin` - nesse caso fiz com versão `jdk1.8.0_92`)

E executa, como está [aqui](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html):

`$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

Assim, vai digitando as informações que vai pedindo. As informações que tu vais precisar são:
`name da keytool` (vai gerar como `my-release-key` provavelmente) e `password`.

**NOTA:** precisei de permissão de admin pra gerar.

Feito isso, pega a keytool recém gerada e coloca em `android/app` no diretório do seu projeto React Native.

Depois, adiciona em `android/gradle.properties`:

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
```

Depois disso, modifica o `android/app/build.grade` como diz no tutorial do React Native:

```
...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
...
```

Aí é só executar:

`$ cd MyAPP/android`
`$ gradlew assembleRelease`

**Obs:** Tive que colocar o **gradlew** no PATH pra rodar o último comando.

Sua apk vai aparecer em `android/app/build/outputs/apk/` após o *build*.

Comment: Oi, gerei meu apk utilizando a explicação que você deixou acima. Upei o apk para o google play, porém, quando faço o download de lá, o mesmo não executa, apenas para de funcionar. Alguma dica?

Comment: testou em seu aparelho?